# Opencart добавляет &amp в URL в панели управления

Tags: php, opencart

Всем привет. У меня вопрос: откуда в URL берется &amp вместо &? И как это исправить?

URL формирую в controller:

`$data['URL'] = $this->url->link('module/products/removeById', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&product_id=' . $data['product_id'], 'SSL');` 
Версия Opencart 2.1.0.2.2

Перехожу на него из view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function removeTrBiID(bidID){
    $.post("<?php echo $URL;?>", {bidID:bidID}, function (data) {
        $('#trRemove'+bidID).hide();
        //   location.reload();
    });
}
//--></script>
```

Когда я его распечатываю он корректный:
`http://mysite.loc/admin/index.php?route=module/products/removeById&token=VDt6AzC2uPS0gCLgiaeClcaFWzrO5Xae&product_id=198`

Когда отправляю на него запрос появляется &amp вместо &:
`http://mysite.loc/admin/index.php?route=module/products/removeById&amptoken=VDt6AzC2uPS0gCLgiaeClcaFWzrO5Xae&ampproduct_id=198`

У кого было такое? Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: наверно за спецсимвол принимает пхп..поставь обратный слэш перед амперсандом

Comment: @Volodymyr пробовал,не помогает

Comment: Нашел в просторах интернета такую строку: $url    .=    str_replace('&',    '&amp;',    '&'    .    ltrim($args,    '&')); Это часть метода url->link. Попробуйте пропустить ссылку через urldecode

Comment: @ilyaplot Находил тоже подобные варианты, но ломать коробку очень не хочется...

Comment: Так это в коробке и есть. Я предлагаю ответ коробки прогонять через decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была подобная ситуация, не ломая функционал коробки можно собрать из заготовок контроллера:

```
$data['URL'] = $this->url->link('module/products/removeById');
$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
```

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function removeTrBiID(bidID){
    $.post("<?php echo $URL;?>&token=<?php echo $token; ?>", {bidID:bidID}, function (data) {
        $('#trRemove'+bidID).hide();
        //   location.reload();
    });
}
//--></script>
```

Пример рабочий, но не знаю насколько верный с точки зрения гуру OpenCarta.